# Jquery - Difference between event.target and this keyword?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

What is the difference between `event.target` and `this`?

Let's say I have

```
$("test").click(function(e) {
    $thisEventOb = e.target;
    $this = this;
    alert($thisEventObj);
    alert($this);
});
```

I know the alert will pop different value. Anyone could explain the difference? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They will be the same if you clicked on the element that the event is rigged up to.  However, if you click on a *child* and it bubbles, then `this` refers to the element this handler is bound to, and `e.target` still refers to the element where the event originated.

You can see the difference here:  http://jsfiddle.net/qPwu3/1/

given this markup:

```
<style type="text/css">div { width: 200px; height: 100px; background: #AAAAAA; }​</style>    
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>​
```

If you had this:

```
$("div").click(function(e){
  alert(e.target);
  alert(this);
});
```

A click on the `<input>` would alert the input, then the div, because the input originated the event, the div handled it when it bubbled.  However if you had this:

```
$("input").click(function(e){
  alert(e.target);
  alert(this);
});
```

It would always alert the input twice, because it is both the original element for the event and the one that handled it.

​

Answer (score 2):

Events can be attached to any element.  However, they also apply to any elements within said object.

`this` is the element that the event is bound to.  `e.target` is the element that was actually clicked.

For example:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <strong><span>click me</span></strong>
  </p>
</div>
<script>$("div").click(function(e) {
  // If you click the text "click me":
  // e.target will be the span
  // this will be the div
});  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Crispy answer

**this** gives you the reference of the **DOM** element where the event is actually attached.

**event.target** gives you the reference of the **DOM** element where the event occurs.

> Long answer

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".outer").click(function(){
    var obj = jQuery(event.target);
    alert(obj.attr("class"));
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
        Outer div starts here
 <div class="inner">
     Inner div starts here
 </div>
</div>
```

When you run the above code snippet you will see that **event.target** is alerting the class name of the **div** that is actually clicked.

However **this** will give the reference of the **DOM** object on which the click event is bind. Check the below code snippet to see how **this** works, always alerting the class name of the div on which the **click** event is bind even if you click the inner div.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".outer").click(function(){
    var obj = jQuery(this);
    alert(obj.attr("class"));
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
    Outer div starts here
    <div class="inner">
     Inner div starts here
    </div>
</div>
```