# replace the anchor tag with a span or div or p

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a functionality where once the user clicks a link, an ajax request is made and if the request is made then the link shouldn't be clickable anymore.

Here is what I'm using to accomplish this:

```
$('a[id^="rsvp_"]').click (function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
        $(this).data('url'),
        function(data) {
            $(this).replaceWith(function(){
                alert (data);
                return $("<span>" + data + "</span>");
            });
        }
    );
})  ;
```

This code will apply to any id starting with `rsvp_` . Everything seems to work including the `alert(data)` however the anchor tag still remains there. I simply want to replace the anchor tag to something else.

The HTML snippet looks like this

```
<a id="rsvp_${event.id}" href="#" data-url="${createLink(action: 'myaction', params: ["eventid": event, "userid": user])}">Click to RSVP</a>
```

**Update**

Please note that I have multiple links like this on the page i.e. `rsvp_1, rsvp_2, rsvp_3 ..etc`

I would just like to remove anchor tag on the link that the user clicked. not all the links on the page

Comment: Do you want to replace the link with the returned data or just make sure the link isn't clicked twice?

Comment: I would like to replace the link with returned data (string) and then make sure that it isn't clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('a[id^="rsvp_"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax($(this).data('url'), {
        method: 'POST',
        context: this
    }).done(function(data) {
        $(this).replaceWith("<span>" + data + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(e.target).replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
    });
```

Comment: This will replace ALL the links. I just want to replace the clicked link

Comment: use this in place of "a[id^="rsvp_"]"

Comment: Use $(this) instead of $("a[id...")

Comment: try e.target in place of this

Comment: You can get detailed analysis at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654141/jquery-different-between-event-target-and-this-keyword

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same by using jquery .one method, which makes sure that each selected element is clickable only once.

In a situation like this, if possible, I would personally change all anchor tags to p or spans by default and then apply click once on the selected elements like:

```
$('p[id^="rsvp_"]').one ("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(
        $(this).data('url'),
        function(data) {
            $(this).replaceWith(function(){
                alert (data);
                return $("<span>" + data + "</span>");
            });
        }
    );
});
```

[more here](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").removeAttr("href");
```

better remove href of anchor.. or

```
  $(this).replaceWith(function(){
      return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
  });
```

Comment: He wants to replace it with the returned data, not just remove the href.