# How to replace an HTML element/tag as a container

Tags: javascript, html

How can I replace the `span`

```
<span id="container"><img src="img.jpg" alt="image" id="content"></span>
```

with an `anchor`

```
<a id="container" href="example.com"><img src="img.jpg" alt="image" id="content"></a>
```

All I can think of is overwriting the whole document using the `document.write` method, which doesn't seem ideal.
Note: I'm looking for a plain JavaScript solution, not jQuery.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090647/replace-the-anchor-tag-with-a-span-or-div-or-p

Comment: I'm looking for a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function I've written for you:

```
function linkify(elementId, url)
{
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId),
        parent = element.parentNode,
        anchor = document.createElement('a');

    anchor.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
    anchor.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    anchor.setAttribute('href', url);

    parent.replaceChild(anchor, element);
}
```

You can use it like so:

```
linkify('container', 'http://example.com');
```

If you'd prefer not to use it as a function, check out [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20418448/revisions) of this answer instead!

Comment: This will only work if the span is the last child of its parent, otherwise the anchor will be in a different location than the original span.

Comment: Your answer and Dilantha's seem to have the same approach. I chose your answer, however, as you were the first respondent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var mySpan = document.getElementById("container");
  var myAnchor = document.createElement("a");
  myAnchor.setAttribute("id","container"); 
  myAnchor.setAttribute("href","example.com"); 
  myAnchor.innerHTML = mySpan.innerHTML;
  mySpan.parentNode.replaceChild( myAnchor,mySpan);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery you can just use

```
var contents = $('#container').contents();
var anchor = $('<a id="container">').attr('href','example.com').append(contents);
$('#container').replaceWith(anchor);
```

Comment: JavaScript only. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, having to hardcode all that is ridiculous anyway.

Comment: hard coding it isn't necessary, I modified it to use the existing image tag. The main point was using the replaceWith function.